# getting the (star-symbol) as input in a c program

Tags: c, windows, mingw, calculator

I just wanted to code a little calculator in C on Windows using gcc 6.3.0 with the operators + - * /.
It works fine, but if I choose *, it lists all files in the directory in my argv[] arrray.
The first for loop is just for debug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    if(argc != 4) {
        printf("\nFalsche Syntax!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    double a,b,c;
    char op;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &a);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &op);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%lf", &b);

    switch(op) {
    case '+':
        c = a + b;
        break;
    case '-':
        c = a - b;
        break;
    case '*':
        c = a * b;
        break;
    case '/':
        c = a / b;
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nUnbekannter Operator!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n\t%.5g %c %.5g = %.5g\n", a, op, b, c);
    
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: ```"*"``` works, it's just not very convenient. ```\*``` listed the directory above. 
I just did this in the windows editor and compiled it using gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Comment: No, it's not convenient, but it's the only way to do it.  In Unix-like shells, the wildcard `*` is expanded to a list of files immediately, before your program even runs, so there's no way for your program to ask for it not to be done.  (In other words, by the time your program starts running, it's too late.) [Edit: based on what bruceg says just below, I may be wrong about "no way to for your program to ask" under MinGW.]

Comment: This is an artifact of MinGW `globbing`. You can try turning it off as shown here: https://willus.com/mingw/_globbing.shtml by adding the external declaration of `_CRT_glob`/

Comment: Other possibilities are: (1) Have your program prompt for the user to type in expressions, rather than fetching them from the invoking command line via `argv`. (2) Rewrite your program to accept "`x`" for multiplication instead of `*`.

Comment: You can also write your expression(s) in a file, then use that file to specify input for your program: `executable.exe <file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an artifact of MinGW `globbing`. You can try turning it off as shown here: https://willus.com/mingw/_globbing.shtml by adding the external declaration of `_CRT_glob`

```
int _CRT_glob = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is MinGW, which is being very helpful and adding wildcard expansion for you. But if you don't want it, you can turn it off.

```
int _CRT_glob = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

Now it doesn't expand `*`.

We note that in other environments, wildcards are expanded by the shell, so this is only effective on Windows. The location of the wildcard expansion (known as globbing) has upsides and downsides.